# How to remove play button from plyr.css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

Hosting a video from VIMEO, need to remove all controllers and play/pause button. All VIMEO related controllers are hidden but still a play button shows in the beginning from plyr.css that I don't know how to hide.
http://www.visualimpacteastwest.com/

Tried to set multiple classes to display:none but still no luck

All I need to remove the play button that shows up in the beginning. Thanks for your help in advance. 
P.S I already have vimeo plus membership and have set all controllers to false from there, this button is from plyr.css

Comment: use the video as a background video. I think its just ?background=1 in the embed

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011183028-Embedding-background-and-chromeless-videos

Comment: I already have that: ......?api=1&background=1&mute=0&loop=1"></iframe> but still it shows up.